# When I try run the code in device it Shows won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: android

won't run unless you update google play services android code

I have added the below lines in my gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

It runs perfectly in some devices but gives such error when trying to run in lower version device

Comment: You have to update google play services in an Android device which giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your play services version in your device. Because lower version devices will have the old play services api that does not support the functions that you specified in your app. So better to update otherwise you'll get these warnings.